# Java for loop-output doesn't display the way I want

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java-coding and I'm stuck at a problem that's been bugging me for the last couple of hours. I'm creating a very small and simple application that will generate a poem. I have four ArrayLists with "Nouns", "Verbs", "Adjectives" and "Adverbs". 
The poem will take one word from each list and put it together to a four-line poem with one word from each list per line, like this:

```
Adverbs Adjectives Nouns Verbs
Adverbs Adjectives Nouns Verbs
Adverbs Adjectives Nouns Verbs
Adverbs Adjectives Nouns Verbs
```

This will create a meaningless poem... anyway.. my problem is that the outcome looks like this:

```
public void generatePoem() {
    adjectives.add("adjective1");
    adjectives.add("adjective2");
    adjective.add("adjective3");
    adjective.add("adjective4");
    nouns.add("noun1");
    nouns.add("noun2");
    nouns.add("noun3");
    nouns.add("noun4");
    verbs.add("verb1");
    verbs.add("verb2");
    verbs.add("verb3");
    verbs.add("verb4");
    adverbs.add("adverb1");
    adverbs.add("adverb2");
    adverbs.add("adverb3");
    adverbs.add("adverb4");



    String thepoem = ""; 


        for (int i=0;i<16;i++) { 
            int count = i + 1; 
            int random = (int)(Math.random()*4);



                    if (count % 2 == 0) { 
                        thepoem += adjectives.get(random).toString() + " "; 
                    } 
                    else if (count % 3 == 0) { 
                        thepoem += nouns.get(random).toString() + " ";
                    } 
                    else if (count % 4 == 0) {
                        thepoem += verbs.get(random).toString() + "\n"; 
                    } 
                    else { 
                        thepoem += adverbs.get(random).toString() + " ";
                    }



        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, thepoem);

}
}
```

The result is random, but it always comes out like this:

```
Adverb Adjective Noun Adjective(?!?!)
Adverb Adjective Noun Adjective(?!?!)
Adverb Adjective Noun Adjective(?!?!)
Adverb Adjective Noun Adjective(?!?!)
```

Where is the verb?

I just can't seem to find the solution... Someone please help me? Again, I'm still in the early stages of Java programming .

Comment: Just an FYI, the random function is not truly random because the seed is the same every time. Read up on [Seeds][1]


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: You don't seem to really understand how the modulo operator works.  Your output also doesn't seem right based on your code.

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at the random function

Comment: Your actual output from the posted code would be `adverb adjective noun adjective adverb adjective adverb adjective noun adjective adverb adjective adverb adjective noun adjective`.  This is different than what you have as your actual output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `count%4==0` then `count%2==0`. Hence, you will never reach the corresponding statement.

```
if (count % 2 == 0) { 

} 

else if (count % 4 == 0) { // <-- You will never reach this statement.

}
```

You should use some modulo 4 only. And it would allow you to use a switch statement.

```
switch (count % 4) {
  case 0 : 
    thepoem += verbs.get(random).toString() + "\n";
    break;
  case 1 :
    thepoem += adverbs.get(random).toString() + " ";
    break;
  case 2 :
    thepoem += adjectives.get(random).toString() + " ";
    break;
  case 3 :
    thepoem += nouns.get(random).toString() + " ";
    break;
}
```

**To go further**, it would be also more elegant to append the Strings with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of using `+=` because `+=` creates a new String with the copy of the 2 previous ones each time.

Example :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0;i<16;i++) {
  ...

switch (count % 4) {
  case 0 : 
    sb.append(verbs.get(random).toString() + "\n");
    break;
  case 1 :
    sb.append(adverbs.get(random).toString() + " ");
    break;

  ....
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

**A bit further**,

As pointed by @IanMcLaird, you can also (actually, you really should) do it without modulos at all (see comments and IanMcLaird's answer).

If I combine IanMcLaird's answer with the StringBuilder, the best solution is IMHO this one :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
  sb.append(adverbs.get(random.nextInt(4)) + " ");
  sb.append(adjectives.get(random.nextInt(4)) + " ");
  sb.append(nouns.get((random.nextInt(4)) + " ");
  sb.append(verbs.get((random.nextInt(4)) + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Reversing the statements doesn't solve the underlying problem with the poster's misunderstanding of modulo though.

Comment: Actually, a cleaner solution would be to use only some modulo 4.

Comment: you might want to mention the fix, which is to change the order of operations so that % 4 is before % 2

Comment: @JimiKimble I edited the answer to show an elegant solution with a switch statement.

Comment: The switch looks more elegant than a bunch of if else, but I guess it's preference at this level. I like it.

Comment: This is a loop switch sequence.  Why use modulo at all?

Comment: @IanMcLaird The purpose of my answer was to explain what was wrong in the OP's code and to show how to better use modulos. But considering the OP's need, your solution is imho the good one (I upvoted it).

Comment: That's fair, but it might be worth pointing out that encoding a set of linear steps as a switch-in-a-loop is generally considered an antipattern.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I edited the answer to point it out and added a solution combining your solution and a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

If count has value 4 then 4%2 == 0 returns true. That's the reason why you get adjective instead of adverb.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could iterate by *line* and not use modulo *at all*.  Also, create a real random generator for more truly random results.

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    thePoem += adverbs.get(random.nextInt(4)) + " ";
    thePoem += adjectives.get(random.nextInt(4)) + " ";
    thePoem += nouns.get((random.nextInt(4)) + " ";
    thePoem += verbs.get((random.nextInt(4)) + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anything that matches your verbs (count%4) will also match (and be consumed by) your adjectives condition (count%2)

Answer (score 0):

Anything which is **divisible by 4** is always **divisible by 2** so your code never reached the divisible by 4 condition hence *no verbs*. One fix is to swap this checking i.e. you first check if it is divisible by 4 then if it is divisible by 2

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if (count % 2 == 0)
```

to:

```
if (count % 2 == 0 && count % 4 != 0)
```

See if you get the right result.

Comment: In the other solution I mentioned changing the order in the if else clause, but that would change the output.  This is the right answer.

Comment: That won't get the desired result.